# MAX_ROWS and AVG_ROW_LENGTH on InnoDB Database - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Do this options works effectively in an InnoDB MySQL database **MAX_ROWS and AVG_ROW_LENGTH** ?

By effectively i want to mean will it have any positive effect !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the option is only for the MyISAM tables, but I am not completely sure about this.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

> **AVG_ROW_LENGTH**
>
> An approximation of the average row length for your table. You need to
>   set this only for large tables with variable-size rows.
>
> When you create a MyISAM table, MySQL uses the product of the MAX_ROWS
>   and AVG_ROW_LENGTH options to decide how big the resulting table is.
>   If you don't specify either option, the maximum size for MyISAM data
>   and index files is 256TB by default. (If your operating system does
>   not support files that large, table sizes are constrained by the file
>   size limit.) If you want to keep down the pointer sizes to make the
>   index smaller and faster and you don't really need big files, you can
>   decrease the default pointer size by setting the
>   myisam_data_pointer_size system variable. (See Section 5.1.4, “Server
>   System Variables”.) If you want all your tables to be able to grow
>   above the default limit and are willing to have your tables slightly
>   slower and larger than necessary, you can increase the default pointer
>   size by setting this variable. Setting the value to 7 permits table
>   sizes up to 65,536TB.

Answer (score 0):

this is may clarifies your doubt..

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: the answer says nothing about INNODB - MAX_ROWS and AVG_ROW_LENGTH